# Unable to Add Account in Xcode->Preference->Account

Tags: xcode, xcode7.2

I am using Xcode 7.2 and i am facing the follwing issue that still i'm unable to resolve after so long.

when i add account to xcode (xcode->preference->Account) it shows following everytime.

[image]

I tried so many times but not getting success, please help me .

Comment: Try to validate your Xcode app. See more details here https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222015a

Comment: Let me check... Thanks for reply